# C++ - Use enum from different header file, same namespace

Tags: c++

I want to be able to use an enum class that is defined in one file, and used in others. When I try I only get this error: `enum "Animal" has no member "Lion"`

I can't find any posts that answer my question.

Here is an example of what I have in mind:
`zooanimals.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace Zoo
{
    enum class Animal;
}
```

`zooanimals.cpp`

```cpp
#include "zooanimals.h"

namespace Zoo
{
    enum class Animal
    {
        Lion,
        Elefant,
        Monkey
    };
}
```

`zoo.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace Zoo
{
    class Visitor;
}
```

`zoo.cpp`

```cpp
#include "zoo.h"
#include "zooanimals.h"

namespace Zoo
{
    class Visitor
    {
        Animal favoriteAnimal = Animal::Lion;
    };
}
```

Comment: Um.. `#include` is used to include headers. So.. `zoo.cpp` would need at least one. Or was that just left out for brevity (and confusion) ? You seem to be declaring a lot of *forward* decls. Any reason for that?

Comment: Sorry, missed that one, thanks.

Comment: If that's your real source, it can't possibly work regardless. There is no `Animal` type (enum or otherwise) for `Zoo::Visitor` to consume, since `zooanimals.h` isn't included, directly or otherwise, in `zoo.cpp`.

Comment: What do you mean by forward declares? Isn't header files supposed to reference all the things that should be included?

Comment: Ooops again, yes, it is included in the original file I have.

Comment: I mean the content of your `zooanimals.cpp` as shown should be in the header, not the cpp.

Comment: Why don't you, as an exercise, replace the include statements in `zoo.cpp` with the contents of those files? This is what the compiler sees when working on `zoo.cpp`. Do you see the source of the error?

Comment: No, not really. It works fine if I replace the include statements. Why does the thing WhozCraig said about defining the enum in the header work and not the way I did it?

Comment: Because in the header it's an incomplete type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't split enums in declaration and definition, so

```
enum class Animal
{
    Lion,
    Elefant,
    Monkey
};
```

should be in the header, not in a source file.

Remember, when you include a header into a source file, this source file can only "see" what is declared in this header. In your case, when the compiler processes zoo.cpp, it can not "see" the values of `Animal`, because they are not in the header.